# Trying to implement DFS instead of BFS

Tags: javascript, class, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

i have implemented BFS to search for a mango seller. However i am about to try it with DFS now - but find it a bit hard. I have tried to to use pop() and unshift() instead, but i still get the same output. I was hoping to see different output. As you can see, i have commented the code, in order to help myself.

```
//We define a graph
class Node {
    constructor() {
        //hash map
        this.connections = new Map()
        //attributes
        this.attributes = new Map()
    }
}

class Graph {
    constructor() {
        //get nodes
        this.nodes = new Node()
    }
    
    //Add node
    addNode(node) {
        this.nodes.connections.set(node, [])
        this.nodes.attributes.set(node, [])
    }
    
    addNodeAttribute(node, attribute) {
        //set a node attribute
        this.nodes.attributes.get(node).push(attribute)
    }

    //Create an edge
    addEdge(source, destination) {
        //if A is friend with B, b is friends with A //undirected 
        this.nodes.connections.get(source).push(destination)
        this.nodes.connections.get(destination).push(source)
    }
    breadthFirstSearch(startingNode) {
        let visitedNodes = []
        let queue = []

        visitedNodes[startingNode] = true
        queue.push(startingNode)

        while (queue.length > 0) {
            const currentNode = queue.shift() //takes the first element
            const connections = this.nodes.connections.get(currentNode)
            
            if (this.nodes.attributes.get(currentNode) == "Mango") {
                return currentNode
            }
            for (let node of connections) {
                if(!visitedNodes[node]) { //if not visited
                    visitedNodes[node] = true //then true
                    queue.push(node) //push node
                }
            }
        }
        return "no mango sellers"
    }
}

let graph = new Graph()

//Create nodes
graph.addNode("Nicolai")
graph.addNode("Alice")
graph.addNode("Claire")
graph.addNode("Peggy")
graph.addNode("Bob")
graph.addNode("Anuj")
graph.addNode("Jonny")
graph.addNode("Thom")

//selling mangoer
graph.addNodeAttribute("Thom", "Mango")

//add edeges
graph.addEdge("Nicolai", "Bob")
graph.addEdge("Nicolai", "Claire")
graph.addEdge("Nicolai", "Alice")
graph.addEdge("Alice", "Peggy")
graph.addEdge("Bob", "Peggy" )
graph.addEdge("Bob", "Anuj")
graph.addEdge("Claire", "Thom")
graph.addEdge("Claire", "Jonny")

console.log(graph.nodes.connections)
```

Comment: Please leave only the relevant part(s) of the code

Comment: Where's your depth-first code?

Comment: Everything here is BFS

Comment: OK, try a depth-first search version, and if you have specific problems then you can post your code and ask about it.